# anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\torch_cuda.dll" or one of its dependencies

Tags: pytorch

I have somehow installed 'transformers' library but on trying to call
from transformers import pipeline.. I get the error :
OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\akalita\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\torch_cuda.dll" or one of its dependencies.

Please help